# batch equivalent of "for i in `cat xx.txt`" in batch scripting

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I am serching a batch scripting option which is quivalent to
"for i in `cat xx.txt`" in unix.

logic of script is

xx.txt has list of folder names which I will be uning in script

```
for i in `cat xx.txt`
do
    cd "e:/test/$i/$yy/$mm/$DD"
done
```

can I have batch equivalent logic for above...

Thanks in advance

Sree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
for /f %%I in (xx.txt) do (
    cd e:\test\%%i\%yy%\%mm%\%DD%
)
```

(Here I assume that variables `yy`, `mm` and `DD` are set to something useful, which you didn't include in the code sample).

You may also need to play with `for /f` options, depending on the directory list file format.
Use `for/?` for details.